# Automatically check access by keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, dom, keyboard-events, wai-aria

We are trying to automatically check our web-application for accessibility. We are therefore looking for ways to automatically check if a certain DOM-Element having an onclick event or beeing an interactive element by definition (like a link, button, checkbox or similar) is accessible by keyboard (e.g. by pressing the TAB key multiple times).

Is there a good standard JS solution (or library) for this? If not, any hints on how this could be achieved in JS?

To simplify things, the solution would also work for us, if the elements that need to be accessible by keyboard must be known (e.g. by a list of CSS selectors).